# How to motorize Technic 42040 Fire Plane

Tags: technic, instructions, motor

Where can I find instructions on how to motorize the Technic Fire Plane.  We have the kit 8293 which contains a motor, battery box, lights and switch, but we have no idea how to attach them.  Will there be instructions online somewhere, or do I need to improvise?

Answer (score 2):

The retail box does not show the usual "+Power Functions" decorations on it so I doubt there are official instructions. Time to get your build on.